# Problems Binding Protocol In Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to bind an objective-c protocol using a Xamarin.iOS binding library. I'm running into issues with the generate interface not being visible to any of my C# code when it compiles. I'm using the [documentation section on Xamarin](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_objc_libs/) where it discusses the "New in MonoTouch 7.0" protocol binding process.

This is my objective-c protocol:

```
@protocol SomeApplicationDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)displayAboutView;
- (void)displaySettingsView;
- (void)displayMessagesView;

- (void)presentSetup;

@end
```

And my ApiDefinition looks like this:

```
[Model, Protocol]
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
interface SomeApplicationDelegate {
    [Export("displayAboutView")]
    void DisplayAboutView();

    [Export("displaySettingsView")]
    void DisplaySettingsView();

    [Export("displayMessagesView")]
    void DisplayMessageView();

    [Export("presentSetup")]
    void PresentSetup();
}

interface ISomeApplicationDelegate {}

[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface SomeApplicationDelegateTool {
    [Export ("getProtocol")]
    ISomeApplicationDelegate GetProtocol ();
}
```

And finally, I'm trying to implement the generated interface/protocol on my AppDelegate:

```
[Register ("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate, ISomeApplicationDelegate
{
    // class-level declarations

    public override UIWindow Window {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public UITabBarController TabBarcontroller {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public override void OnResignActivation (UIApplication application)
    {
    }

    public override void DidEnterBackground (UIApplication application)
    {
    }

    public override void WillEnterForeground (UIApplication application)
    {
    }

    public override void WillTerminate (UIApplication application)
    {
    }

    public void DisplayAboutView() {        
    }

    public void DisplaySettingsView(){
    }

    public void DisplayMessageView(){
    }

    public void PresentSetup(){
    }
}
```

This is my output from the build log:

```
Compiling to native code
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -sdkroot "/Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer" --cache "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache" --nomanifest --nosign -dev "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/bin/iPhone/Debug/SomeiPhone.app" -r "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iOS.Raw/bin/Debug/Some.iOS.Raw.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" -debug -linksdkonly -sdk "8.0" -targetver "7.0" --abi=armv7,armv7s "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/bin/iPhone/Debug/SomeiPhone.exe"
Xamarin.iOS 7.9.3 Trial Edition using framework: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk
Process exited with code 1, command:
/Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang  -lxml2 -lz -Wl,-pie  -arch armv7 -arch armv7s -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/SomeiPhone.exe.armv7.o" "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/SomeiPhone.exe.armv7s.o" "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/monotouch.dll.armv7.o" "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/monotouch.dll.armv7s.o" "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/mscorlib.dll.armv7.o" "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/mscorlib.dll.armv7s.o" "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.dll.armv7.o" "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.dll.armv7s.o" "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Some.iOS.Raw.dll.armv7.o" "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Some.iOS.Raw.dll.armv7s.o" "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/registrar.armv7.o" "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/registrar.armv7s.o" "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/main.armv7.o" "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/main.armv7s.o" -force_load "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/libSome.a" -o "/Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/bin/iPhone/Debug/SomeiPhone.app/SomeiPhone" -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework CFNetwork -framework MobileCoreServices -framework MessageUI -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -lz -liconv -u _mono_pmip -u _monotouch_log -u _monotouch_release_managed_ref -u _monotouch_create_managed_ref -u _xamarin_get_block_descriptor /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.a /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch-debug.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/SomeiPhone.exe.armv7s.o, file was built for armv7s which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/SomeiPhone.exe.armv7s.o
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/monotouch.dll.armv7s.o, file was built for armv7s which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/monotouch.dll.armv7s.o
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/mscorlib.dll.armv7s.o, file was built for armv7s which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/mscorlib.dll.armv7s.o
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.dll.armv7s.o, file was built for armv7s which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.dll.armv7s.o
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Some.iOS.Raw.dll.armv7s.o, file was built for armv7s which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Some.iOS.Raw.dll.armv7s.o
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/registrar.armv7s.o, file was built for armv7s which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/registrar.armv7s.o
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/main.armv7s.o, file was built for armv7s which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/dfrisk/Dev/temp/Some Prototype/Some.Mobile/Some.iPhone/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/main.armv7s.o
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SomeApplicationDelegateTool", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in registrar.armv7.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SomeApplicationDelegateTool. If '_OBJC_CLASS_$_SomeApplicationDelegateTool' is a protocol from a third-party binding, please check that it has the [Protocol] attribute in its api definition file, otherwise verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.
```

I'm new to creating a binding so I'm not sure how to figure out exactly what is wrong. From what I can tell, it looks like I've followed the steps correctly. And I seem to have all the same framework references that are in my xcode project.

My linkWith.cs has this:

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("libSome.a", LinkTarget.Simulator | LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.ArmV7s, ForceLoad = true, Frameworks = "MobileCoreServices CFNetwork MessageUI CoreGraphics CoreLocation MapKit QuartzCore SystemConfiguration UIKit Foundation AddressBook AddressBookUI", LinkerFlags = "-lxml2 -lz")]
```

I had problems getting the libxml2 and libz libraries linked up, but I think that is ok now.

From what I understand of the process and what the documentation says, its seems like my interface should be available. Intellisense shows the ISomeApplicationDelegate available under the library namespace, but at compile time I get the build errors. I'm not sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

Comment: Your bindings have extra definition, e.g. for `startupAnimation`, and even *new* type `SomeApplicationDelegateTool`. Do they exists in ObjC ? If so please add their description to your question. If no then it's your error (i.e. you only bind native code, if you need something else you implement it inside your application using C#).

Comment: the `startupAnimation` was leftover from a method that I didn't want to bind (edited)
`SomeApplicationDelegateTool` is modeled after the [Xamarin documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_types_reference_guide/). According to the docs, its a new way to implement protocols that allow you to add the generated protocols as an interface rather than a base class. In my case, I want to implement the protocol as an interface since I need to extend from UIApplicationDelegate. I was following the code block thats about 1/2 way down the page.

Comment: looks like my problem was because there was a main.m file in my static library -- which was conflicting with the Xamarin app. Didn't realize it was there. I copied most of the files from a different xcode project and that must have came along with it in the process.